# Where to change this store variable

Tags: store-id

On [this page](http://smartcoffee.company/contacts), the `Smart Coffee Australia / APAC` is pulled from a setting somewhere.

The rest is taken from `Configuration > Store Information`.

Do you know where I can change this?

`Configuration > Store Information > Store Name` is set to `Smart Coffee APAC Pty Ltd`

Comment: I disagree with the closing of this question. The OP *did* provide a source for us to look at. Although his question might have been theme-specific, he did not necessarily know that at the time, and mentioned what he *did* try to solve it himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is actually coming from the built-in Magento contacts module. Judging by the HTML source code of the page, it looks like somebody extended the stock `form.phtml` -- it's **there** that you should find your answer as to where the data is coming from (could even be hard-coded).

So you'll want to look at `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/contacts/form.phtml` where `[package]/[theme]` depends on the actual design package in use. If you don't find the file in the custom theme, it's possible also that the core template has been modified, in which case that is found in `base/default`.

Answer (score 0):

This is too difficult to answer as far as I know. Because the heading `Smart Coffee Australia / APAC` can come from anywhere. Why do you think it is coming from a setting ? Is there any specific reason for that ? If there is a reason, please share it with us and you will get more detailed assistance here.

`Contact Us` page that you are mentioning is a `CMS/Page` I think. So first and basic step that you need to take is, go to `CMS > Pages` in admin menu find the page which is correspond to this contact us page. Hopefully you can find the text there. If it is not there, then you need to look for any blocks are included in that cms page either via layout update or via direct injection of block unit inside the content section of the page. In either way you need find the templates associated with the page and go through them and find where it is generating